# How can I define some arguments of a C macro as another macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

Consider the macro

```
#define IP4_ADDR(ipaddr, a,b,c,d)  (ipaddr)->addr = PP_HTONL(LWIP_MAKEU32(a,b,c,d))
```

I would like to define the arguments a,b,c,d in another macro. So I have done this:

```
#define DEBUG_HOST_IP4 192, 168, 0, 123

IP4_ADDR(&debug_host, 192, 168, 0, 123 );
IP4_ADDR(&debug_host, DEBUG_HOST_IP4 );
```

The first call to IP4_ADDR compiles succesfully, while the second one fails with

> error: macro "IP4_ADDR" requires 5 arguments, but only 2 given
>   IP4_ADDR(&debug_host, DEBUG_HOST_IP4 );

Is there a way to make `DEBUG_HOST_IP4` expand properly, so the `IP4_ADDR` macro can work as intended?

EDIT: The IP4_ADDR macro comes from a third-party library, which I would rather not touch, and risk breaking somebody else's code. Of course, implementing my own version is an option.

Comment: Boost.Preprocessor has [`BOOST_PP_EXPAND`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), the implementation of which you could inspect. Boost is C++, but the two languages' preprocessor is similar in many respects and this particular macro should be portable.

Comment: Check [this article](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic), especially the sections about expansion and recursion.

Comment: The no doubt unwelcome but most sensible advise is get rid of the macros in the first place. `IP4_ADDR` looks like an excellent candidate for a function.

Comment: You cannot change the way the preprocessor expands macros, so your alternatives are to change the macro or to change every use of the macro. I added the second option to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't alter IP4_ADDR, this is still pretty easy; just wrap it:

```
#define MY_IP4_ADDR(...) IP4_ADDR(__VA_ARGS__)
```

During the translation (which just moves all of the arguments over, whatever they are), any macros will expand.  Then just use your wrapped version in the code.

```
  MY_IP4_ADDR(&debug_host, 192, 168, 0, 123 );
  MY_IP4_ADDR(&debug_host, DEBUG_HOST_IP4 );
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can make your outer macro a varargs macro:

```
#define IP4_ADDR(ipaddr, ...)  (ipaddr)->addr = PP_HTONL(LWIP_MAKEU32(__VA_ARGS__))
```

The macro invocation must have the correct number of arguments. The inner macro invocation works because arguments are expanded before the body is rescanned.

The varargs syntax allows you to either supply the four arguments or use a macro which expands to them.

If you don't want to alter the definition of `IP_ADDR`, you invoke it indirectly through a wrapper macro:

```
#define CALL(macro, __VA_ARGS__) macro(...)
// ...
CALL(IP4_ADDR, &debug_host, DEBUG_HOST_IP4 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the second part, I had a similar solution in mind. I will accept after testing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define like this:

```
#define IP4_ADDR(ipaddr, HOST)  (ipaddr)->addr = PP_HTONL(LWIP_MAKEU32(HOST))
```

DEGUB_HOST_IP4 will be replaced only in second part. So when you passed it as parameter, it was replaced only to a, and b, c, d was ignored